# How do I Order Boxes on One boxplot graph? (r)

Tags: r, boxplot

I've read the answers to several questions of this type, so sorry for the repeat, but I had trouble understanding how they applied to how my data is laid out.

What I would like is to order the boxes on my boxplot (which has, say, four boxes) in the order I wish as opposed to alphabetically.

This is a simplified version of my current code:

```
TotalPer = c(1, 4, 6, 17, 4, 12)
IntPer = c(3, 8, 10, 1, 4, 8)
DomPer = c(4, 5, 10, 20, 13, 12)

IntDomBox <- data.frame(y=c(TotalPer,IntPer,DomPer),
x=c(rep("Total",length(TotalPer)),rep("International",length(IntPer)),
rep("Domestic",length(DomPer))))
with(IntDomBox, boxplot(y~x, main = "Prediction Residuals", ylab="%",
par(cex.axis=0.7)))
```

This produces a boxplot in alphabetical order. If I prefer to have the boxplot in the order listed in the dataframe (Total, Int, Dom) how would I do this? I know about making it reverse alphabetical instead, but in some cases that is not what I want, so I'd prefer to be able to manually assign the order.

Thanks!

Comment: That's great, thanks! I'm not sure how to mark this as the answer since it's a comment, so I may just rewrite it up as an answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility out of many: Reorder the factor levels before plotting by executing `IntDomBox$x <- factor(IntDomBox$x, levels=unique(IntDomBox$x))`